# owl carousel - not working online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Owl slider is not working online, but when i try it in localhost it is working. Please help! Thanks. This is the link http://mobile.best0709.cafe24.com/pls.html
I inserted it to a korean CMS shopping mall.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Owl Carousel - One slide</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="jQuery Responsive Carousel - Owl Carusel">
    <meta name="author" content="Bartosz Wojciechowski">




    <!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
    <link href="/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/owl.carousel.js"></script>
   <style>
    #owl-demo .item img{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    </style>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true,
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem : true,
      autoPlay : 1000

      // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
      // items : 1, 
      // itemsDesktop : false,
      // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      // itemsTablet: false,
      // itemsMobile : false

      });
    });
    </script>



  </head>
  <body>





      <div id="demo">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
              <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

                <div class="item"><img src="/web/upload/slider-011.png" width="100%" alt=""></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="/web/upload/slider-011.png" width="100%" alt=""></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="/web/upload/slider-011.png" width="100%" alt=""></div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>










    <!-- Demo -->



    enter code here



  </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Look at the console: "undefined is not a function " at pls.html:26

Comment: Check your browser's dev tools. Something goes wrong with your js `TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function` (as K K said)

Comment: @K K @antithesis Yes i see those errors. Maybe it is script conflict???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, yes there were some conflict issues in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mobile.best0709.cafe24.com/ind-script/optimizer.php?filename=2989881215a2d3fbb5b7fc82d14d65358165348d_1411447623&type=js&"></script>
```

Above file causes the conflict. If you remove this file, your code works fine.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/v2z46gf5/1/

If you include this file, the code doesn't work:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v2z46gf5/

Comment: Thank you very much @K K. But this script is generated by  the cms.

Comment: There must be some documentation on how to avoid conflicts. Have a look at it's documentation